# Angularjs and typeahead, how getting rid off [object Object]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a view using a input text with uib-typeahead.
The input text is into a form.

When loading the view, the input text shows "[object Object]" about 5 seconds, before to be filled with the data loaded from remote server.
After the data to be loaded from remote server, all shows ok.

Is there a way to avoid this [object Object] into input text before the view is completelly loaded with the data from server?

I have tried ng-cloak but it has no effect.

//markup

```
<div class="col-sm-9 col-lg-9" id="scrollable-dropdown-menu">
   <script type="text/ng-template" id="templatePac.html">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
               <a href>
                <span ng-bind-html="match.model.nome  | uibTypeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
                <span> - CPF:</span>
                <span ng-bind-html="match.model.cpf || 'sem cpf'"></span> 
               </a>
            </div>
   </script>
    <input type="text" ng-model="paciente"  required
    uib-typeahead="item as item.nome for item in getPacientesByName($viewValue)" 
    ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: {'default': 500, 'blur': 0}}" 
    typeahead-editable="false" typeahead-select-on-exact="true" query="query"  typeahead-wait-ms="300"  typeahead-loading="loadingLocationsPac"   typeahead-template-url="templatePac.html" typeahead-no-results="noResultsPac" class="form-control">
    <div>
      <i ng-show="loadingLocationsPac" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
      <div ng-show="noResultsPac">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Sem resultados
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

//js controller

```
angular.module('clinang').controller('menuPacientesEvolAtendAddController',  function($scope,$state,$http) {
 $scope.paciente={primeiro_atendimento:{prescricao_adotada:{medicamentos:[]}}};
 ...
 ...

 $scope.getPacientesByName=function(val){
              return $http.get(urlBase+'/configuracao',{params:val}).then( (response)=>{
                   return response.data
               }, (erro)=>{
                      console.log(erro);
              })
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is it possible at all to get the data on a resolve so that you get the data before your view is rendered

Comment: try select>option and use ng-option. see if it works. or let us know what sort of ui design you want to achieve ? r u using bootstrap?

Comment: @ Molik Miah This is an option to try if no other solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you modify $scope.paciente initial value to have "nome", field according to typeahead value in input, so typeahead could parse it properly? 
e.g.

```
$scope.paciente={nome: "", primeiro_atendimento:{prescricao_adotada:{medicamentos:[]}}};
```